# Rounding function in a windowed range in PostgreSQL 14

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I can't find a good example about how you inline round a windowed function. I have tried putting the Round function everywhere (besides the right place) in the example below. Price is a double. How do you inline Round function on windowed results from operators like avg?

nine_day_avg should be rounded to two digits in this example.

```
SELECT quote_date,price, 
       avg(price)
       OVER(ORDER BY  quote_date ROWS BETWEEN 8 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS nine_day_avg   
       FROM quote_datas
       where symbol = 'A'
       order by quote_date desc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ROUND (source [ , n ] )` as

```
source is a number or a numeric expression that is to be rounded
n is an integer that determines the number of decimal places after rounding
```

**NOTE :**  n is optional and if omitted default value is 0.

You must cast the value to be rounded to numeric to use above mentioned version of `round`.

```
SELECT quote_date, price, 
round(avg(price::numeric) OVER(ORDER BY quote_date ROWS BETWEEN 8 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), 2) AS nine_day_avg
FROM quote_datas where symbol = 'A' order by quote_date desc
```

Comment: org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function round(double precision, integer) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: cast your price to numeric and apply round operation. See I have updated my answer.

Comment: I'm new to PostgreSQL, is casting like this a big performance hit as it is in client code?

Comment: For performance cast is the fastest function than other data type conversions

Answer (score 0):

You just need to apply round function to the entire avg() windowed column name including over clause. So it can be as follows -

```
SELECT quote_date,price, 
       round(avg(price) OVER(ORDER BY  quote_date ROWS BETWEEN 8 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),2)
 AS nine_day_avg   
       FROM quote_datas
       where symbol = 'A'
       order by quote_date desc
```